# Apache Poi: get page count in DOC document

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to get page count in DOC document using Apache Poi?

I try to use the following piece of code:

```
HWPFDocument wordDoc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(lowerFilePath));
Integer pageCount = wordDoc.getSummaryInformation().getPageCount();
```

But got exception (version of Apache Poi: 3.13)

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(Ljava/io/InputStream;I)[B
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocumentCore.verifyAndBuildPOIFS(HWPFDocumentCore.java:95)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:174)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231134/how-to-avoid-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-poi-util-ioutils-copyljava

Comment: See http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006 - you have old versions of POI on your classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work properly. The reason of this very common POI error is that an older version of the library on your classpath in which the method didn't exist yet. And also some versions of parts from the library are incompatible.

If you use maven you need only these dependencies for this piece of code:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>${poi.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
  <version>${poi.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you do not have extra versions of jars.

Answer (score 2):

The lower version of Apache POI has some compatibility issues and also some functions are not supported. I also had the same problem, so I upgraded to version 4.0.1 of Apache POI.

If you use maven dependencies, then you can use this.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```