# How to get number of page of msword file?

Tags: java, android, api, ms-word

How to get a number of pages of msword file in the android studio ??
I know the URI of that file. 
I don't want to open that file in my app.
is it possible to know the number of pages of msword file?
 if yes how??

Comment: This has already been answered. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510867/apache-poi-get-page-count-in-doc-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510867/apache-poi-get-page-count-in-doc-document)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Apache API](http://poi.apache.org/) for word Docs:

It has a method for getting the page count:

```
public int getPageCount()
```

It will return the page count or 0 if the SummaryInformation does not contain a page count.

Comment: can you share some link to learn basics about Apache API? I am a beginner.

Comment: https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android

Comment: use the above link

Comment: here is exact sample project about apache POI
https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/poi-android

Comment: If you want to work with Excel you can also concern with this link
http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/creatingreading-an-excel-file-in-android/